# Time Machine Server on Fedora

Tags: fedora, rhel, backup, macintosh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I (and should I) use my Linux file server as a Time Machine backup server for my Macs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-can-i-and-should-i-use-my-linux-file-server-as-a-time-machine-backup-serve)

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to/or knew of a good guide to setting up mac Time Machine backup server on a Fedora 17 machine.

I recently ran into an issue with my HDD and lost all of my data, so I don't want it to ever happen again, as it was quite traumatising.

I just want to be able to back all of my data up on my Fedora machine from my Mac, at scheduled times when I connect to my home network. If anyone could help, it would be fantastic, I searched around on Google, but all of the ones I found were for older distros.